# Moving company abroad?

Tags: taxes, international

I work for a British agency now, but I'm outsourced for a German project that is partially remote and I'm going to be based mostly in Poland.
Not sure how long will be the contract, but it made me think if I should move the company to Poland?
Maybe, in this case, I could also move my company to tax heaven like HK or Belize? Any experience with that?
My accountant has no much clue about international law.

Answer (score -1):

Since this is very general I will offer a general answer.

Here is the general *confused belief*:

## "Using a company in Belize/etc I pay no tax on freelance!!

Now here is precisely the error in that thinking:

## Every penny you bring back to the UK/US/Etc, you pay tax on just the same. No difference whatsoever.

This is the basic total confusion about the idea behind "no tax in belize for freelancers!"

Say

1. you live in the UK and Google pays you $100,000 for a job.
2. you then of course pay normal UK taxes of all types on $100,000.  Let's say $30,000 for clarity.

Now compare this

1. you live in the UK
2. Google pays $100,000 to BelizeSoft for a job. No tax in Belize, yay. So there's $100,000 sitting in the BelizeSoft bank.
3. BelizeSoft pays you $100,000
4. you then of course pay normal UK taxes of all types on $100,000.  Let's say $30,000 for clarity.

## There is utterly no advantage. Nothing.

Every cent you repatriate to the UK, you just pay tax on totally normally. Utterly no difference if BelizeSoft pays you or Google pays you.

It's that simple.

*Hopefully this explains the base confusion about "freelancing through a tax haven!"*

{Obviously, not even mentioned here are the sundry downsides (thousands a year to (pointlessly) maintain such a company, etc etc).  And the upsides (in some arcane fields, you may get legal protection doing this, but it's utterly irrelevant to say programers).}

Comment: This answer needs some references to back these claims up.  It's common practice for mutlinationals to have complex structures to minimize tax paid in the EU (and elsewhere) so clearly there is some tax benefit at some point.

Comment: multinationals have no relationship, though, to an individual trying to "freelance through a tax haven".

Comment: regarding a "reference" that you have to pay tax in the UK - I'm not really sure what that would be!   :)  perhaps https://www.gov.uk/topic/personal-tax/income-tax

Comment: If you don't live in the UK you don't have to pay taxes in the UK. If there are lower taxes in poland and you move to poland and then work from poland you pay taxes in poland. It's slightly more complicated if you have a business, but nothing prevents you from opening a new business in poland that works for your new employer

Comment: XY - "If you don't live in the UK you don't have to pay taxes in the UK." of course, obviously.   This post is about the case of people trying to use "tax haven companies" to reduce tax.